# full screen option not working in youtube iframe in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

i have a website where i gave youtube video, as I wanted to give separate thumbnail I gave the following code:

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 youtube" style="height: 130px; width: 240px;  " src="http://molugu.com/yantraev/divayoutubethumb.jpg" id="h4cYkgPnYQk" >

<iframe   src="https://youtu.be/h4cYkgPnYQk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://codegena.com/assets/js/youtube-embed.js"></script>
```

here when I play the video its working but, when I click on the fullscreen option its showing fullscreen is unavailable, can anyone please tell me how to fix it,thanks in advance

Comment: When you hover the full screen icon there's a link to tell you why it may not work: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72689?visit_id=637606418695612300-2542538696&rd=1. In addition to that, modern browsers may restrict displaying cross-domain iframe content in fullscreen mode for security and usability reasons.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i clicked that, its showing full screen might be disabled, but I didnt disable it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using this script  https://codegena.com/assets/js/youtube-embed.js

This is disallowing it use this code instead

```
<div id="your_id">

<iframe width="240px" height="130px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h4cYkgPnYQk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>


</div>
```

Comment: am trying to add custom thumbnail, so I used it

Comment: You can also add custom thumbnail by yourself without any external library

Comment: You may want to use:
style="max-width: 240px; max-height: 130px;"
Instead of the iframe widht/height properties to ensure responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use [video.js](https://videojs.com/) instead of the old youtube iframe or codegena.

Video.js is an ideal solution to embed video from various external sources (youtube, vimeo etc) and use them in a single video player. It offers endless customization options to adapt the look, feel and functionality of the player.

You can use it with a single html video tag like this:

```
<video
id="vid1"
class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
controls
width="640" height="264"
data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/h4cYkgPnYQk"}] }'></video>
```

View this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/xshadowcrowx/pen/rNmaYxR) example to see it in action.

Comment: video not loading bro